# Best way to account for time lags in logistic regression (GLM or GLMM)

Tags: time-series, logistic, generalized-linear-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am trying to determine the best, most conservative way to account of time lags in a logistic regression type analysis (a generalized linear model with or without mixed effects).

I am working with time-series data. For each of several hundred independent sites, I have a measured binary response variable (1 or 0, such as presence/absence data) and a dynamic predictor variable which is specific to each site and time point. *(In a biomedical analogy, these could be a set of patients measured in a longitudinal study).* I want to predict the binomial response variable based on the value of the predictor variable from the previous time step. However, it is supported both theoretically and empirically that the response variable at time *t* is correlated with the response variable at time *t - 1* and that temporal autocorrelation decays through time (i.e., AR-1). But in the context of this study, this is not very interesting and we don't really care about the strength of autocorrelation *per se*. The main question is, **How does the response variable at time *t* depend on the predictor variable at time *t – 1* while controlling for temporal autcorrelation in the response variable?**

I have come across potential ways of addressing this and hoping the Cross Validated community can help me determine the most conservative and least biased approach.

I'm using R, so below is the notation I might use (e.g., with the package *lme4*). Assume that the dependent variable is *y.t* at time t and *y.t.previous* at time t – 1,  and predictor variable at time t – 1 is *x.t.previous*.

(1) Use a generalized linear mixed-effects model (GLMM) and include the site as a random effect

```
    glmer(y.t ~ x.t.previous + (1|site), data=dat, family=binomial)
```

(2) Use a generalized linear model and include the lagged dependent variable (LDV) as a fixed effect:

```
    glm(y.t ~ x.t.previous + y.t.previous, data=dat, family=binomial)
```

(3) Use a GLMM with the LDV as a predictor as a *random* effect:

```
    glmer(y.t ~ x.t.previous + (1|y.t.previous), data=dat, family=binomial)
```

(4) Use a GLMM with the LDV as a predictor and a random effect of site:

```
    glmer(y.t ~ x.t.previous + y.t.previous + (1|site), data=dat, family=binomial)
```

(5) Specify AR1 covariance structure, but it is unclear to me how to do this in a generalized linear model (mixed or otherwise).

Thanks for your thoughts!